# Cannot assign RefObject<HTMLDivElement> to RefObject<HTMLElement> instance

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In a React component I want to keep a reference to a child node which can differ in type (div, img etc.). So I defined a member variable:

```
export class MyComp extends Component<IProperties, IState> {

    private triggerRef = React.createRef<HTMLElement>();

...
}
```

and want to use that to hold the required ref:

```
    const trigger = <div ref={this.triggerRef} className={className} style={style} />;
```

Though, this produces an error:

```
Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Property 'align' is missing in type 'HTMLElement' but required in type 'HTMLDivElement'.ts(2322)
lib.dom.d.ts(6708, 5): 'align' is declared here.
index.d.ts(143, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'
```

The line `Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'` says the two ref object types are incompatible, even though `HTMLDivElement` extends `HTMLElement`. I'd expect that the ref types are assignment compatible as they clearly have an overlap.

What is the correct approach here, without changing the member variable to use `HTMLDivElement`?

Comment: Is creating a union feasible? I.e. `private triggerRef = React.createRef<PossibleHTMLElements>();` where `type PossibleHTMLElements = HTMLDivElement | HTMLImageElement | ... =`

Comment: Yes, that's a possible way. I discussed that already in the (now deleted) answer from @keikai. Though I'm more interested in why I cannot assign a reference with type `HTMLDivElement` to one with type `HTMLElement`. The elements are directly compatible, just not the ref types.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is not really an answer to my original question, but an easy workaround and it does the job nicely:

```
const trigger = <div 
    ref={this.triggerRef as React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>}
    className={className}
    style={style}
/>
```

Answer (score 33):

For all people coming to this thread because they encounter this problem when writing a custom hook doing something with a DOM Element, the following works:

```
function useMyCustomHook<T extends HTMLElement>{
    const myRef = useRef<T>(null)

    // do something with the ref, e.g. adding event listeners

    return {ref: myRef}
}

function MyComponent(){
    const {ref: myElementRef} = useMyCustomHook<HTMLDivElement>()

    return <div ref={myElementRef}>A Div</div>
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
private triggerRef = React.createRef<HTMLElement>();
```

to the specific element type:

```
private triggerRef = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();`
```

And then `ref={this.triggerRef}` will work (without needing to cast like `ref={this.triggerRef as React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>}`).

Comment: What if I want to store a ref to an HTMLButtonElement there? Please read my question again: it asks explicitly about a solution **without** changing the ref variable type.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

`const refPanel_1 = useRef<null | HTMLDivElement>(null);`