# How do I type a ref that is used on arbitrary elements with React and TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React Hook that can be used on arbitrary elements (anything that extends `HTMLElement`) to detect whether the element is hovered. When attempting to type the usage, I'm unable to satisfy the TypeScript compiler. Here's a simple reproduction:

```
function useHover<T extends HTMLElement>(): [MutableRefObject<T>] {
  const ref = useRef<T | null>(null);
  return [ref];
}

const App = () => {
  const [ref] = useHover<HTMLButtonElement | HTMLAnchorElement>();
  const Element = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'a' : 'button';

  return <Element ref={ref}>{`tag: ${Element}`}</Element>;
};
```

Within the Hook, I don't know what element type will be used, so I use a generic with the `extends HTMLElement` constraint. Within the React compoment, however, I do know the limited subset of element types that the ref will be used with.

With the above code, I get this type error:

```
Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLButtonElement | HTMLAnchorElement>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLAnchorElement> & LegacyRef<HTMLButtonElement>'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLButtonElement | HTMLAnchorElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLAnchorElement> & RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>'.
    Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLButtonElement | HTMLAnchorElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLAnchorElement>'.
      Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
        Type 'HTMLButtonElement | HTMLAnchorElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAnchorElement'.
          Type 'HTMLButtonElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLAnchorElement': charset, coords, download, hreflang, and 19 more.
```

What would be the correct way to type this Hook and component so that I can use the Hook on any element that extends `HTMLElement`?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to type a `ref` which

- holds an element (`T extends HTMLElement`) and
- will be controlled by React (you intend to pass it to the `ref` prop of the JSX element)

is `RefObject<T>`. Reference [the type declaration file which defines `useRef`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/22439e6e9b4e57eac897a8538b80610ad950adb8/types/react/index.d.ts#L1053):

> `function useRef<T>(initialValue: T|null): RefObject<T>;`

Here's how you can write a hook which returns a ref like that:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbxgTzAUzgJTQMwPIBGAVmgMYwA0cArgM5rY4C+cOUEIcA5FGgIbkuAbgBQInNQB25YBEk16AUQA2aEGkkxGcADwAVOGgAeMDQBNacABJ6AsgBkVajTAB8ACgCUALiy5CJOT6rogicHCkcrTwvDhwALwKDLjB7pLUysqeouG8MNRQ8rGiTEA)

```ts
import {type RefObject, useRef} from 'react';

function useElementRef <T extends HTMLElement>(): RefObject<T> {
  const ref = useRef<T>(null);
  return ref;
}
```

However, you don't need to use a `ref` for a "useHover" hook (determining whether an element is hovered by a pointer or not). See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70093450/438273) for that.

Comment: Using a `RefObject` instead of a `MutableRefObject` triggers the same type error.

Comment: @dstaley In your specific example, you can use an intersection `&` of element types `useElementRef<HTMLAnchorElement & HTMLButtonElement>()` instead of a union `|`, to satisfy the compiler diagnostics: however, this is not type-correct. There is not a way to randomly generate an element type (unknown at compile time) and get a type-safe ref. TypeScript is _compile-time only_, so you must discriminate between every element type you intend to use in order to have type safety.